# pip does not install dependency declared in setup() requires parameter

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a Python project which depends upon the `wsgi_intercept` package. I added it to the `requires` parameter from my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup( #...
       #...
       requires = [ 'wsgi_intercept',
               # ...
       ]
 )
```

Then I execute the `sdist` command:

```
$ python setup.py sdist upload
```

However, when I install the package with `pip`, it does not install `wsgi_intercept` and my package  cannot work correctly.

What am I missing? Should I add another configuration to `pip`. I read about the `pip` requirement files but they seem to be used by the deployer, not de distributor.

Comment: @okm maybe... but this project is a fork of one that already uses `setuptools` and I am really focused on getting it working. Nonetheless, I will try `distribute` at some moment in the near future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the keyword args of `distutils.core.setup()` are [changed](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#new-and-changed-setup-keywords). I use `install_requires` in my `setup.py` and it works fine.

Change the keyword `requires` to `install_requires` and see if it works.